# pyppeteer wait until all elements of page is loaded

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, pyppeteer

I am using **pyppeteer** to trigger headless chrome and perform some actions. But first I want **all the elements of the web page to load completely.** The official documentation of pyppeteer suggests a **waitUntil** parameter which comes with more than 1 parameters.

My doubt is do i have to pass **all the parameters or any one in particular** is sufficient? Please suggest if following snippet helps in my case?

```
await page.goto(url, {'waitUntil' : ['load', 'domcontentloaded', 'networkidle0', 'networkidle2']})
```

Answer (score 8):

No, you don't have to pass all possible options to `'waitUntil'`. You can pick either of them, or more options at the same time if you like, but if you are:

- not deailing with a single-page app,
- not interested in all network connections (like 3rd party trackings for example)

then you are good to go with: `'domcontentloaded'` to wait for all the elements to be rendered on the page.

```
await page.goto(url, {'waitUntil' : 'domcontentloaded'})
```

The options in details:

- `load`: when `load` event is fired.
- `domcontentloaded`: when the `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired.
- `networkidle0`: when there are no more than 0 network connections
  for at least 500 ms.
- `networkidle2`: when there are no more than 2 network connections
  for at least 500 ms.

[[source]](https://pyppeteer.github.io/pyppeteer/_modules/pyppeteer/page.html#Page.goto)

*Note:* of course it is true for the NodeJs puppeteer library as well, they work the same way in terms of `waitUntil`.

Comment: What do you mean by single-page app? the webpage that i am loading will be anyway a single page

Comment: I mean it is e.g. written fully in React.Js or Angular and only functional once all the js bundles are downloaded to the client https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application. If that is the case you will need to use the `networkidle0` option to make sure your page is fully functional, the `DOMContentLoaded` event may fired earlier than this would happen.