# Puppeteer parse dom before load event

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, browser-automation

In my puppeteer script, I am trying to open a website which takes 4-5 min. for page load event to complete. Thats because the ads(particularly video ads) on page take very long time.
So here is my code snippet:

```
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(link, {timeout: 0});
  // wait until anchor with class=author is visible
  await page.waitForSelector('a[class="author"]', {timeout: 0});
```

In above code, the default is `'waitUntil': 'load'` as per puppeteer [documentation](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.waitforoptions) so the line `await page.waitForSelector(...)` takes 4-5min. to reach. However the selector element I am looking for gets visible immediately as its not loaded via any script. So how do I get rid of this long delay due to having to wait for page load to finish?

Comment: might [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62852714/pyppeteer-wait-until-all-elements-of-page-is-loaded) help

Comment: [Avoid `{timeout: 0}`](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#using-infinite-timeouts). There's never a good use case for blocking forever--better to expire after a few minutes so you can get a clear error and handle the failure. I would block those ads. You can also use [`{waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"}`](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#never-using-domcontentloaded) which is faster than `"load"`. Can you share the site? All I can do is guess answer without it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `domcontentloaded` instead of `load`.

```js
await page.goto(link, {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
```

From the MDN docs about [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event),

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading (the load event can be used to detect a fully-loaded page).